# Self-Calibration in Aerial Computer Vision

Tags: computer-vision

I have read that there are 4 common procedures for auto-calibration in Computer Vision:

- Mendonca & Cipolla's Method
- Classical Kruppa's Method
- Simplified Kruppa's Method
- Dual Absolute Quadric Method

I also understand that one can use the Bundle Adjustment to refine the calibration values, however this suffers from sensitivity to initial values.

The above methods are known to be degenerate for Aerial photogrammetry ([paper](http://cell.missouri.edu/media/publications/conference_071817.pdf)). Are there any standard self calibration procedures for Aerial CV that can generate an initial guess to be further refined in a bindle adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

With vertical (nadir) views also BA would fail. If you run BA with free intrinsic parameters  the correlation between the height from the ground and the focal length will likely produce wrong results for both. In other terms, changing the focal length or the camera height has locally the same effect, and so the optimiser get fooled.

Comment: Unless you have control points?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention.